# How to check the g++/clang++ default linked libraries

Tags: ubuntu, boost, g++, clang++

Just installed the boost libraries on Ubuntu 12.04 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I used the following command to compile&build the code without any problems even if I didn't provide the required boost libraries explicitly.

```
g++ $1.cpp -o $1 -g -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic -std=c++0x
Or
clang++ -o $1 -Werror $1.cpp -std=c++11 -O3

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<int> shpInt(new int(10));

  cout << *shpInt << endl;

  boost::tuple<int, double, std::string> triple(42, 3.14, "my first tuple");
  cout << triple.get<0>() << endl;
  cout << triple.get<1>() << endl;
  cout << triple.get<2>() << endl;
}
```

Question> How can I check the default linked libraries used by g++ or clang++?

Thank you

Comment: These boost libraries are header-only. There are no files to feed to a linker.

Comment: Neither `boost::shared_ptr` nor `boost::tuple` need that a library be linked, they are header-only libraries. You can see [here](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries) a list of the libraries that need to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

Add -v to the compile command line:

g++ $1.cpp -o $1 -g -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic -std=c++0x -v

Then look for collect2 or ld. Clang is similar.